# Grep not matching certain parts of man page

Tags: bash, macos, grep, manpage

Grep doesn't seem to match certain strings from `man` output. It seems to be random in that I can't work out any rhyme or reason as to whether a string will match or not.

`man sed | head -7`:

```
SED(1)                    BSD General Commands Manual                   SED(1)

NAME
     sed -- stream editor

SYNOPSIS
```

```
$ man sed | head -7 | grep sed # no match

$ man sed | head -7 | grep stream # match on "stream"
     sed -- stream editor

$ man sed | head -7 | grep '\-\-' # match on "--"
     sed -- stream editor

$ man sed | head -7 | grep NAME # no match

$ man sed | head -7 | grep SYNOPSIS # no match
```

This also happens when redirecting the output to a file and grepping that

```
$ man sed | head -7 > /tmp/sed.man

$ cat /tmp/sed.man | grep sed # no match

$ cat /tmp/sed.man | grep stream # match on "stream"
     sed -- stream editor

$ grep sed /tmp/sed.man # no match

$ grep stream /tmp/sed.man # match on "stream"
     sed -- stream editor
```

grep: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
man: version 1.6c
macOS: 10.14.6 Beta
bash: GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0)

```
$ man sed | head -7 | hexdump -C
00000000  0a 53 45 44 28 31 29 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.SED(1)         |
00000010  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 42 53 44 20 47  |           BSD G|
00000020  65 6e 65 72 61 6c 20 43  6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64 73 20  |eneral Commands |
00000030  4d 61 6e 75 61 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |Manual          |
00000040  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 53 45 44 28 31 29 0a  |         SED(1).|
00000050  0a 4e 08 4e 41 08 41 4d  08 4d 45 08 45 0a 20 20  |.N.NA.AM.ME.E.  |
00000060  20 20 20 73 08 73 65 08  65 64 08 64 20 2d 2d 20  |   s.se.ed.d -- |
00000070  73 74 72 65 61 6d 20 65  64 69 74 6f 72 0a 0a 53  |stream editor..S|
00000080  08 53 59 08 59 4e 08 4e  4f 08 4f 50 08 50 53 08  |.SY.YN.NO.OP.PS.|
00000090  53 49 08 49 53 08 53 0a                           |SI.IS.S.|
00000098
```

Googling is hard for this problem as any combination of "man" or "grep" doesn't mention my problem that strings (with no special characters) are not matching.

Comment: Sorry, macOS, I'll add that

Comment: All is working for me, Ubuntu Linux

Comment: did you try `man --ascii sed | head -7 | grep sed`

Comment: my guess is that man detects the output to be a file or not and adapts content

Comment: I got `unrecognized option '--ascii'` and couldn't find `ascii` in `man man` either

Comment: Add output of `man sed | head -7 | hexdump -C` to your question if `hexdump` is available.

Comment: try `man -t sed | ps2ascii | head -7 | grep sed `

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have `ps2ascii`, I've found out I can pipe through `col -bx` which seems to work

Answer (score 1):

man-pages are using the roff-format (https://man.openbsd.org/roff). Do the following:

```
man sed > sed.man
vi sed.man
```

so you see:

```
SED(1)                    BSD General Commands Manual                   SED(1)

N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE
     s^Hse^Hed^Hd -- stream editor
```

to convert a man-page to text without the ^H-stuff. have a look on http://www.schweikhardt.net/man_page_howto.html#q10

create a perl-Skript called `strip-headers` with the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wn
#  make it slurp the whole file at once:
undef $/;
#  delete first header:
s/^\n*.*\n+//;
#  delete last footer:
s/\n+.*\n+$/\n/g;
#  delete page breaks:
s/\n\n+[^ \t].*\n\n+(\S+).*\1\n\n+/\n/g;
#  collapse two or more blank lines into a single one:
s/\n{3,}/\n\n/g;
#  see what is left...
print;
```

change the rights on the perl-script `chmod 750 strip-headers` and run it with:

```
man sed | ./strip-headers | col -bx > sed.man
```

or

```
man sed | ./strip-headers | col -bx | head -7 | grep sed
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting that. I didn't realise `cat sed.man` and `vi sed.man` would display different output. Do you know what this formatting is called or how to fix it without `--ascii`?

Comment: it is called roff-format. may be you can convert it with groff.

Answer (score 1):

macOS man doesn't support the `--ascii` flag, so I used `col -bx` to strip the annoying formatting from man for piping into other commands.

```
man sed | col -bx | grep SYNOPSIS
```

col -b: Do not output any backspaces, printing only the last character written to each column position.
col -x: Output multiple spaces instead of tabs.

Notes:
I've read that man is meant to detect whether you're piping to another command or into a file, etc, but that was not my experience. At least for man 1.6c, the default for macOS.
Solution using `col`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15866
Thanks @Cyrus - I didn't know about `hexdump`
Thanks @Oliver Gaida - I didn't know cat and vi would show display differently